# HTML Javascript - Posicion y color de lineas en canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy trazando con canvas pero necesito que las lineas que aparecen esten detras los rectangulos y tambien que cada linea tenga su propio color

Codigo del canvas

```
<script>
        //X,Y
        function start () {
            var element = document.querySelector('canvas')
            element.width = window.innerWidth;
            element.height = window.innerHeight;
            var s1 = element.getContext("2d");
            var s2 = element.getContext("2d");
            var s3 = element.getContext("2d");
            var s4 = element.getContext("2d");
            s1.fillRect(110,110,100,100);
            s2.fillRect(220,300,100,100);
            s3.fillRect(400,200,100,100);
            s4.fillRect(800,500,100,100);


            s1.beginPath(); 
            s1.moveTo(250,330);
            s1.strokeStyle = "Gray";
            s1.lineWidth = 3;
            s1.lineTo(120,120);
            s1.strokeStyle = "blue";
            s1.lineTo(440,250);
            s1.stroke();

            s2.beginPath();
            s2.lineWidth = 2;
            s2.moveTo(850,550);
            s2.strokeStyle = "green"; 
            s2.lineTo(240,330);
            s2.strokeStyle = "green"; 
            s2.lineTo(450,250);
            s2.stroke();

        }

        window.addEventListener("load",start, false);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existe una propiedad del context que te permite definir *cómo* añadir elementos: [`CanvasRenderingContext2D.globalCompositeOperation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation)

Indicando `contexto.globalCompositeOperation='destination-over';`, haces que las nuevas figuras se sitúen *detrás* de las existentes:

```js
function start () {
    var element = document.querySelector('canvas')
    element.width = 1000;
    element.height = 1000;
    var s1 = element.getContext("2d");

    s1.fillRect(110,110,100,100);
    s1.fillRect(220,300,100,100);
    s1.fillRect(400,200,100,100);
    s1.fillRect(800,500,100,100);
//a partir de aquí, todo lo que añadamos estará "detrás"
    s1.globalCompositeOperation='destination-over';

    s1.beginPath(); 
    s1.moveTo(250,330);
    s1.strokeStyle = "Gray";
    s1.lineWidth = 3;
    s1.lineTo(120,120);
    s1.strokeStyle = "blue";
    s1.lineTo(440,250);
    s1.stroke();

    s1.beginPath();
    s1.lineWidth = 2;
    s1.moveTo(850,550);
    s1.strokeStyle = "green"; 
    s1.lineTo(240,330);
    s1.strokeStyle = "green"; 
    s1.lineTo(450,250);
    s1.stroke();

}

window.addEventListener("load",start, false);
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta sin duda lo que necesitaba, me ayudaste mucho, una ultima cosa, tengo aun mas dudas, pero es mi deber investigar por ello solo quisiera saber que documentacion debo leer para aprender las propiedades?

Comment: Yo lo busco todo en [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Canvas), es el lugar más completo sobre las tecnologías web. Lamentablemente hay cosas que no están traducidas al español, pero para mí eso no es un problema

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias por el consejo

Answer (score 1):

No entiendo muy bien tu problema, ¿por qué no sólo dibujar después los rectángulos?
Son cosas muy diferentes strokeStyle y fillStyle, uno es el color de la líneas y el otro el color de relleno, en todo caso de que si se deseara mantener el color digamos del strokeStyle se pueden usar las funciones save() y restore().

```
<script>
    function start () {
        var element = document.querySelector('canvas')
        element.width = window.innerWidth;
        element.height = window.innerHeight;
        var s1 = element.getContext("2d");

        s1.beginPath(); 
        s1.moveTo(250,330);
        s1.strokeStyle = "Gray";
        s1.lineWidth = 3;
        s1.lineTo(120,120);
        s1.strokeStyle = "blue";
        s1.lineTo(440,250);
        s1.stroke();

        s1.beginPath();
        s1.lineWidth = 2;
        s1.moveTo(850,550);
        s1.strokeStyle = "green"; 
        s1.lineTo(240,330);
        s1.strokeStyle = "green"; 
        s1.lineTo(450,250);
        s1.stroke();

        s1.fillRect(110,110,100,100);
        s1.fillRect(220,300,100,100);
        s1.fillRect(400,200,100,100);
        s1.fillRect(800,500,100,100);
    }

    window.addEventListener("load",start, false);
</script>
```

Ejemplo usando save() y restore()

Ver el código [save and restore](https://codepen.io/JesusTepec/pen/aqMgOb/) by Jesus Tepec ([@JesusTepec](https://codepen.io/JesusTepec)) on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/JesusTepec/pen/aqMgOb?editors=1010)

Comment: Estás asumiendo que las líneas se pueden dibujar antes, pero quizá los rectángulos se dibujen y sea el usuario el que, haciendo click en dos rectángulos, añada las líneas que los unen. En ese caso reordenar el dibujado no ayuda

Comment: Tienes razón, pero ahí la diferencia es que ya estás planteando un  problema más específico y claramente tu respuesta sería la precisa.

Comment: Tienes razon es mas sencillo tu resolucion, ya vi el codigo y pienso que es mucho mas sencillo, ahora saben si existe alguna forma de agregar un id a cada rectangulo, es decir que al hacer clic en cada rectangulo se dibujen sus lineas pero se unan con otro rectangulo en especifico?